# Duplicate JSON-LD scripts in head

Tags: html, json-ld, structured-data

I have to inject multiple `script` elements for JSON-LD data into the `head` of my application, all pertaining to the same `@type`. This is due to pulling in different fields from different data source.

Will this duplication cause any problems?

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@type": "Organisation",
        "name": "John Smith"
    }
</script>

<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@type": "Organisation",
        "city": "London"
    }
</script>
```

I'm hoping this will be translated by Google as simply:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@type": "Organisation",
        "name": "John Smith",
        "city": "London"
    }
</script>
```

Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

Consumers can’t/shouldn’t assume that these JSON objects describe the same thing. (Think of a web page with information about many different organizations: it would of course be wrong to assume that they are the same organization.)

JSON-LD allows you to specify that the things described in different objects are identical: give them the same `@id` value.

`@id` takes an IRI which acts as identifier (it’s [useful to provide them for many reasons](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/98578/17633)).

See [Node Identifiers](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#node-identifiers) in the JSON-LD spec.

So it could look like this (using Schema.org instead of your custom vocabulary):

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Organization",
        "@id": "/organizations/42#this",
        "name": "ACME"
    }
</script>

<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Organization",
        "@id": "/organizations/42#this",
        "description": "…"
    }
</script>
```

(The relative URL `/organizations/42#this` would represent the organization itself. It’s best practice then to provide this JSON-LD as well your information about the organization under `/organizations/42`.)