# Can I use @id to join multiple JSON-LD scripts to a valid object?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

Is this valid? I need an opportunity to join diffrent script blocks on one page to a valid object.

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Product",
  "@id": "#111",
  "description": "Test description",
  "name": "My Product"
}
</script>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Product",
  "@id": "#111",
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "3.5",
    "reviewCount": "11"
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: [Duplicate JSON-LD scripts in head](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45876849/1591669)

Answer (score 0):

why should these scripts be joined? They describe the same product and are partly redundant.

But if you are looking for possibility to join scripts by id - yes, it exists. I.e. you have two scripts: first - product and its rating, second - organization offering this product. In this case the joining would look like:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "Organization",
"makesOffer": {
"@type": "Offer",
"itemOffered": {
"@type": "Product",
"@id": "https://www.example.com#111"
}
}
}
</script>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "Product",
"id": "https://www.example.com#111",
"aggregateRating": {
"@type": "AggregateRating",
"ratingValue": "3.5",
"reviewCount": "11"
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I often do that when the review system adds its own markup separately to the product markup. It works fine.

You can test it in the Structured Data Testing Tool. It should merge the two into one.