# Can a product's structured data be split into separate sections?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I'm working on a site optimizing their structured data and noticed they use YotPo to pull in ratings and reviews. YotPo is defining the `Product` and only has a couple of values for `AggregateRating` that are being injected via JavaScript.

I have all of the other product data coming from the CMS, so I defined all the other information there, but when I run Google's testing tool on the page, it sees it as 2 products and says it's missing fields for the YotPo markup that are already defined in my markup.

Is there some way to let Google know that they're both chunks of data for the same product so it only sees it as a single product with the combined data?

Comment: [Duplicate JSON-LD scripts in head](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45876849/1591669) ··· [Duplicate schema/structured data markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48532381/1591669)

Comment: I'm in a similar situation, were you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure both Yotpo and your CMS use the same format. e.g. json-ld or microdata.

You can then indicate that they relate to the same product by setting both up to use the same id.